# do {} while won't terminate

Tags: c, while-loop, do-while

I'm a super beginner programmer. Basically I have got this code:

```
int main()
{        
    char name[30];
    printf("Name of the animal exchange: \n");
    scanf(" %s", &name);

    char animalname[14];
    int quantity = 0;
    int quantitysum;        
    int type = 1;

    do {        
        printf("A(z) %d. fajta neve: \n", type);                
        scanf(" %s", &animalname);

        while(strlen(animalname)<15) {                                    
            printf("Quantity: \n");
            scanf(" %d", &quantity);
            quantitysum += quantity;
            break;            
        }

        if(strlen(animalname)<15) {
            type++;            
        }        
    } while (animalname != "");
}
```

I thought the loop was supposed to stop with an enter pressed as stated in the while. What's the problem?

Comment: You can't compare strings with `!=`.

Comment: `animalname!=""` don't compute what you think (it compares memory address not contents). If you want to compare strings use `!strcmp(animalname,"")`.

Comment: You should enable all warnings & debug info in your compiler (e.g. compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my string comparison fail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069925/why-does-my-string-comparison-fail)

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare strings with `!=`, since that will only compare the *pointers*. Instead, you have to use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) or a similar function:

```
while (strcmp(animalname, "") != 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fgets()` to get input. `%s` format specifier won't scan anything when you press just enter whereas `fgets` does scan it. Also,change

```
scanf(" %s", &name);
```

to

```
scanf(" %s", name);
```

This is done because the name of an array decays to a pointer to its first element.Replace the below `scanf` with `fgets`:

```
scanf(" %s", &animalname);
```

Also,string comparision must be done by using `strcmp()` function from `string.h`. By using `==`,you compare the pointers(Recall that array names decay to a pointer to its first element).Your full code will look like

```
int main()
{        
    char name[30];
    printf("Name of the animal exchange: \n");
    scanf(" %29s", name); //scan at-most 29 (+1 for the `\0`)

    char animalname[14];
    int quantity = 0;
    int quantitysum=0; //initialize to zero        
    int type = 1;

    do {        
        printf("A(z) %d. fajta neve: \n", type);                
        fgets(animalname,14,stdin);

        if(strlen(animalname)<15) {  //You have a break in the loop which means that you need an if as it will execute just once                 
            printf("Quantity: \n");
            scanf(" %d", &quantity);
            quantitysum += quantity;
            type++; //This can be done here itself
            //break;             
        }

        /*if(strlen(animalname)<15) {
            type++;            
        } This is done in the previous if*/       
    } while (strcmp(animalname,"")!=0);
}
```

Note that your `if` will always be true as `fgets()` limits the amount of characters that it reads. So you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

It wont terminate because the condition in the while does not change.....want a c# guide buy thus book http://shoppingict.blogspot.com/2014/12/book-ultimate-c-guide-for-dummies.html?m=1